# Equal in select does not work as expected

Tags: pdo

I found a funny behaviour using equal with pdo. I checked several select-statements in phpmyadmin and pdo and the results vary. Has someone a idea whats wrong?

```
$sql = "select * from fenster where fenster > 'news'";  //works ok
$sql = "select * from fenster where fenster < 'news'";  //works ok
$sql = "select * from fenster where fenster <= 'news'";  //works ok

$sql = "select * from fenster where fenster >= 'news'";  // news is not in result
$sql = "select * from fenster where fenster = 'news'";   // news is not in result

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql); 
$stmt->execute();
```

**$feldName = array_keys($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));**

```
while($data = $stmt->fetch()) {
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason myself.
The $feldName = array_keys($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)); did read the missing row, so it did not show afterwards. So I have to find a workaround.